# Issues redirecting from login page

Tags: php, ajax

I am taking a course in webdevelopment.  Currently, i am building a web page where people can take notes.  My registration form works fine, activation works, db values are created with username and password.  The issue is, when trying to login with activated username and password, it does not redirect to my logged in page.  I have tried many things and just cant find where the issue is.  I tested my connection to database and everything seems working.  I compared the code with my course instructor, and cant find any difference. However, his works, mine doesn't.  Thank you for any suggestions!

Here is my code with Ajax call for login form

```
   $("#loginform").submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();

    console.log(datatopost);

    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datatopost,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "success"){
                window.location = "mainpageloggedin.php";
            }else{
                $("#loginmessage").html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#loginmessage").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax Call.  Please try again later!</div>");`


        }
    });
});




    <?php
session_start();

//Connect to database

include("connections.php");


//Check user inputs
//    Define error messages

$missingEmail = '<p><strong>Please enter your email!</strong></p>';
$missingPassword = '<p><strong>Please enter a password!</strong></p>';

if(empty($_POST["loginemail"])){

$errors .= $missingEmail;

}else{
    $email = filter_var($_POST["loginemail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

}
//GET PASSWORDs

if(empty($_POST["loginpassword"])){

    $errors .= $missingPassword;

}else{
        $password = filter_var($_POST["loginpassword"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

if($errors){
    $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors . '</div>';
    echo $resultMessage;

}else{


    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);

$password = hash('sha256', $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password='$password' AND activation='activated'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if(!$result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';

    exit;
}


if($count !== 1){

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong username or password</div>';


}
    else{
    //log the user in: set session variables
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
    $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];

//        header('location: mainpageloggedin.php');


}


}


?>
```

Thank you

Comment: You `header` line is commented out... and you don't seem to echo "success" anywhere either so neither option will work. Also somewhat concerned this is the kind of code that an "instructor" is putting to students. :S

Comment: I tried with the header too and would not work.  This is not part of the instructors code.  I commented it out because it wouldn't work either.  Thanks

Comment: Well yes, the `header` option won't work with AJAX, if it was just a simple form submission it probably would, in the case of the AJAX one, it's probably not working because it's expecting a return value of "success" but you're not sending it.

Comment: Once I hit "submit" i get "success" above the username in the login form, but will not redirect.

Comment: Then at a guess you're returning success, probably wrapped in some HTML. Check your Network tab of your browser's dev tools and see what the AJAX request is getting returned.

Comment: Can I you show you a print screen?

Answer (score 0):

use `serialize` instead of `serializeArray` for submit the form:

```
$("#loginform").validate({
      rules: {
            loign_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            login_password: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            login_password: "Please enter a valid password",
            loign_email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "success"){
                    window.location = "mainpageloggedin.php";
                }else{
                    $("#loginmessage").html(data);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#loginmessage").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax Call.  Please try again later!</div>");`

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code and i just get redirected to the main page. It redirects me even if i do not place values in the form.

Comment: Thanks patel but same errors again.  The code that i have asks for password and username when empty but when you put your updated code, nothing prompts me to put values in.  No errors come!  I just get redirected to the previous page.  If you have any other suggestions please let me know.